Is there a temporary vibrate analogous to temporary mute?
I have a Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra running Android 14.
I've noticed that if I set it on mute, it will ask me if I want the mute to be temporary, and if I answer Yes, it asks me for how long.
I had a meeting to attend today, so a couple of days ago I set an alarm scheduled to wake me today and remind me of the meeting.  It didn't wake me, so I missed my meeting!
When I investigated why, I found that it was because I'd set it to Vibrate mode last night, so I could be alerted to incoming text messages without disturbing everyone attending the meeting I was at last night.  The functionality that would have solved the problem would be similar to the Temporary Mute functionality I described above, but set to vibrate instead of mute.  Do Android phones have a Temporary Vibrate function that would allow me to set it to notify me by vibrating during a specific period of time, and then when that time is up automatically switch to notifying me by playing the ringtone?
